# Is there a MATLAB way of verifying whether a function does not satisfy triangle inequality of metric spaces?

Tags: matlab, math, verification

I was trying to show that the function, d(x,y)=(|x-y|)/(1+|x+y|) , does not satisfy triangle inequality of metric spaces. I tried the following MATLAB code. Is this code doing good work?

For the function d(n,m) satisfies the triangle inequality if
d(n,m)<=d(m, k)+d(k, n) in a given set. In this case real numbers.

```
function check2

x=rand(1,1000);
y=rand(1,1000);
z=rand(1,1000);

f=[];
g=[];
h=[];
p=[];
for i=1:length(x)
   f(i)= abs(x(i)-y(i))/(1+abs(x(i)+y(i)));
   g(i)=abs(x(i)-z(i))/(1+abs(y(i)+z(i)));
   h(i)=abs(z(i)-y(i))/(1+abs(z(i)+y(i)));
   p(i)=f(i)<=g(i)+h(i)
   if p(i)==0
       v=[h(i), g(i), h(i)]
       break;
   end
end

f'
```

Comment: I think you'll have to explain further what a metric space is. What is your goal here?

Comment: What is the function you’re testing? Is it f(n)=[x(n),y(n),z(n)]?

Comment: Yes, but I am failing to type in latex here @CrisLuengo

Comment: @GuarneerFPS I will edit the question

Comment: You cannot do LaTeX, but that doesn’t mean you can’t explain better what you are attempting to do. As it stands, it’s hard to know what you are asking.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have included as per your comment and modified the question

Comment: How easy do you expect to find the counterexample? You're just testing random points, what if they all pass? There isn't a rigorous way to check every real number, so it's not really clear how you expect to "verify" whether or not your function satisfies this inequality, unless you expect to easily find an example of it not doing so in which case you should inform your input choice with that expectation (i.e. picking targeted values) instead of praying on the Gods of `rand` to deliver

Comment: @Wolfie this problem is a method of promoting and protecting human rights. Instead of you cracking your head you use this code. Secondly, you can take this one as probability question of finding how likely someone can find counter example given that s/he is guessing. In future, you shall see how useful this code is. Not all random numbers pass. Try this code on your laptop, not all random numbers among the one thousand are passing.